# Error while replacing values in numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

In the foll. numpy array, I want to replace any values matching -1.0 with 0.0

```
array([[ 89.75,  90.  ],
       [ 89.5 ,  89.75],
       [ 89.25,  89.5 ],
       ..., 
       [-89.5 , -89.25],
       [-89.75, -89.5 ],
       [-90.  , -89.75]], dtype=float32)
```

However, this gives an error:

```
var[var == mask_val] = default_val # mask_val is -1.0 and default_val is 0.0

*** IndexError: Index cannot be multidimensional
```

Comment: syntax seems right, are you sure about the variables' values?  Replace them with hard-coded values, are you getting the same error?

Comment: thanks @karafka, tried hardcoded values, but they do not work either, same error

Comment: Your example works just fine for me.  You're certain the error is happening at the line you've posted?

Comment: Yeah, I think a complete example that demonstrates the error would be very helpful.